# Foursquare API: Android key hash does not match the allowed key hashes specified in the app's settings

Tags: android, hash, key, foursquare

I'm trying to create Android application based on Fousquare API. I need to connect to foursquare account. I generated keys as told in instructions: [github - foursquare-android-oauth](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth) But result is "Connecting failed". Client id and client secret are in app's settings. What's wrong?

Logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1355): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.foursquare.android.sample/.MainActivity } from pid 1507
D/WindowManagerImpl( 1355): addView, new view, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40d5af98
W/dalvikvm( 1507): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
W/dalvikvm( 1507): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
D/SensorService( 1355): enable: get sensor name = BMA150 3-axis Accelerometer
D/Sensors ( 1355): Enable akm: en = 1
D/SensorService( 1355): SensorDevice::activate--: handle = 0x0, enabled = 0x1
D/SensorService( 1355): enable: sensor->activate return value = 0x0
D/SensorService( 1355): enable: calling mActiveSensors.add(handle, rec) = (0x0, 0x991fc8)
D/SensorService( 1355): enable: mActiveConnections.indexOf(connection) = 0x0
D/SensorService( 1355): pid=1355, uid=1000
D/AK8975  ( 1260): Compass Start
V/WindowManager( 1355): Starting animation in AppWindowToken{408c6f78 token=HistoryRecord{409ded10 com.htc.launcher/.Launcher}} @ 27969582
V/WindowManager( 1355): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{408c6f78 token=HistoryRecord{409ded10 com.htc.launcher/.Launcher}} @ 27969582
V/WindowManager( 1355): Starting animation in AppWindowToken{40e6f250 token=HistoryRecord{40a891d0 com.foursquare.android.sample/.MainActivity}} @ 27969582
V/WindowManager( 1355): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{40e6f250 token=HistoryRecord{40a891d0 com.foursquare.android.sample/.MainActivity}} @ 27969582
D/AK8975  ( 1260): Ignore M_Sensor: (y, p, r) = ( 139,    0,    3), Status = 0
D/ATRecorder(19226): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@4053d0e0
D/WindowManagerImpl(19226): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40538ca8
D/WindowManagerImpl( 1355): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40d5af98
I/ActivityManager( 1355): Displayed com.foursquare.android.sample/.MainActivity: +210ms
V/ActivityManager( 1355): Checking to restart com.foursquare.android.sample.MainActivity: changed=0x0, handles=0x0
V/ActivityManager( 1355): oldConfig={ scale=1.0 imsi=250/1 loc=ru_RU touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=61 skin=default fontsize=3}
V/ActivityManager( 1355): newConfig={ scale=1.0 imsi=250/1 loc=ru_RU touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=61 skin=default fontsize=3}
D/lights  ( 1355): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/green/brightness string=0,len=1
V/NotificationService( 1355): Charging...
D/lights  ( 1355): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/green/blink string=0,len=1
D/lights  ( 1355): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/green/off_timer string=0 0,len=3
D/lights  ( 1355): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/amber/brightness string=1,len=1
D/lights  ( 1355): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/amber/blink string=0,len=1
D/lights  ( 1355): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/amber/off_timer string=0 0,len=3
V/NotificationService( 1355): Turn off Charm Ind LED
W/InputManagerService( 1355): [unbindCurrentClientLocked] Disable input method client.
W/InputManagerService( 1355): [startInputLocked] Enable input method client.
D/BatteryService( 1355): SendIntentforPowersaver
D/BatteryService( 1355): Current powersaver status == NORMAL_STATUS
D/WifiService( 1355): [smart wifi] mSmartWiFiStatus: 0 mBatteryLevel: 88 mWifiConnected: true
D/WifiService( 1355): [smart wifi] ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 2
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1507): plugged = true, health = 2, level = 88, mPluggedBatteryLevel = 87, mLowBatteryWarningLevel2 = 25, mshowLowChargingWarning2 = true
E/MyHTC   ( 1643): [ImmediateModeProxyMgr] Failed to connect; wait some amount of time before trying again.
W/System.err( 1643): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
W/System.err( 1643):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1643):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
W/System.err( 1643):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
W/System.err( 1643):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:440)
W/System.err( 1643):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1013)
W/System.err( 1643):    at com.htc.handsetlib.proxy.ImmediateModeProxy.connect(ImmediateModeProxy.java:195)
W/System.err( 1643):    at com.htc.cs.service.ImmediateModeProxyMgr._connectToImcOrStatusServer(ImmediateModeProxyMgr.java:134)
W/System.err( 1643):    at com.htc.cs.service.ImmediateModeProxyMgr.onIntent(ImmediateModeProxyMgr.java:198)
W/System.err( 1643):    at com.htc.cs.service.ImmediateModeService$PushHandler.handleMessage(ImmediateModeService.java:708)
W/System.err( 1643):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1643):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
W/System.err( 1643):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
D/MyHTC   ( 1643): [ImmediateModeProxyMgr] _connectToImcOrStatusServer(): Fail IMC reconnect time = 172000
D/View    (19226): onTouchEvent: viewFlags: 0x18004001
D/View    (19226): onTouchEvent: isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: false, isFocused: false; focusTaken: false
I/ActivityManager( 1355): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=foursquareauth://authorize?client_id=AP5RF0GZVCLPHHQ5HLHD5KQSYG03XIQUTKV1LXFCEQHPYMKS&v=20130509&androidKeyHash=60%3AA4%3AD9%3A06%3A0E%3AD2%3A27%3A56%3A00%3A57%3AF6%3A5D%3AE0%3AB7%3A65%3A39%3AC2%3AA9%3A64%3A34 cmp=com.joelapenna.foursquared/.OauthWebViewActivity } from pid 19226
E/ResourceType( 1355): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010397
E/ResourceType( 1355): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
D/WindowManagerImpl( 1355): addView, new view, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40dce998
I/keystore( 1257): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
I/ActivityManager( 1355): Start proc com.joelapenna.foursquared for activity com.joelapenna.foursquared/.OauthWebViewActivity: pid=19512 uid=10077 gids={3003, 1015}
V/WindowManager( 1355): Starting animation in AppWindowToken{40e6f250 token=HistoryRecord{40a891d0 com.foursquare.android.sample/.MainActivity}} @ 27971452
V/WindowManager( 1355): Starting animation in AppWindowToken{40d58910 token=HistoryRecord{40b2cf48 com.joelapenna.foursquared/.OauthWebViewActivity}} @ 27971452
V/WindowManager( 1355): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{40e6f250 token=HistoryRecord{40a891d0 com.foursquare.android.sample/.MainActivity}} @ 27971464
V/WindowManager( 1355): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{40d58910 token=HistoryRecord{40b2cf48 com.joelapenna.foursquared/.OauthWebViewActivity}} @ 27971464
D/dalvikvm(19512): GC_CONCURRENT freed 139K, 44% free 3202K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(19512): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 41% free 3529K/5959K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+2ms
I/dalvikvm(19512): Could not find method android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder.detectCustomSlowCalls, referenced from method com.joelapenna.foursquared.Foursquared.d
W/dalvikvm(19512): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1630: Landroid/os/StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder;.detectCustomSlowCalls ()Landroid/os/StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder;
D/dalvikvm(19512): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0011
D/dalvikvm(19512): VFY: dead code 0x0014-003f in Lcom/joelapenna/foursquared/Foursquared;.d ()V
I/ActivityThread(19512): Pub com.joelapenna.foursquared: com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.GlobalSearchProvider
I/ActivityThread(19512): Pub com.joelapenna.foursquared.db.ConversationsContentProvider: com.joelapenna.foursquared.db.ConversationsContentProvider
I/ActivityThread(19512): Pub com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.VenueQuerySuggestionsProvider: com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.VenueQuerySuggestionsProvider
I/ActivityThread(19512): Pub com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.AppSearchSuggestionProvider: com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.AppSearchSuggestionProvider
I/ActivityThread(19512): Pub com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.foursquarebridgeprovider: com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.FoursquareBridgeProvider
I/ActivityThread(19512): Pub com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.FriendsSearchSuggestionProvider: com.joelapenna.foursquared.providers.FriendsSearchSuggestionProvider
I/keystore( 1257): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
I/keystore( 1257): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
I/keystore( 1257): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
I/keystore( 1257): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
I/keystore( 1257): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
I/keystore( 1257): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
I/dalvikvm(19512): Could not find method android.os.StrictMode$VmPolicy$Builder.detectLeakedClosableObjects, referenced from method com.foursquare.core.h.z.a
W/dalvikvm(19512): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1638: Landroid/os/StrictMode$VmPolicy$Builder;.detectLeakedClosableObjects ()Landroid/os/StrictMode$VmPolicy$Builder;
D/dalvikvm(19512): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0025
D/dalvikvm(19512): VFY: dead code 0x0028-0038 in Lcom/foursquare/core/h/z;.a ()V
```

Comment: Because your Keyhash is not matching with the keyhash you provided in foursquare

Answer (score 0):

follow this link:

> https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

it's much more informative and explains the process great.

by the way it would be greate if you could paste the exact error and give some more information about what you did....theres not enough info to help you.

Comment: thanks, I read it already. I create keystore via Eclipse, then use "keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore", after paste hash to app's settings. Why can't keyhash match with the keyhash in foursquare?

Comment: can you paste the logcat here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't set the INTERNET PERMISSION in the Android manifest:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No, I set it. Problem was in keystore. I used new keystore, not debug.keystore